# How to get Android Thread ID?

Tags: android

This code throws a "Given thread does not exist" exception when I try to use it in a thread:

```
android.os.Process.getThreadPriority((int) Thread.currentThread().getId()));
```

Ditto if I try to use Process.setThreadPriority, using the java class Thread id. I've also noticed that this does not match the thread id displayed in the debugger. How do I get the Android specific thread id, in order to use this API?

Comment: Have you checked whether `Process.myTid()` is any use for you?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

```
android.os.Process.getThreadPriority(android.os.Process.myTid());
```

For further reference

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process.html#myTid()

Comment: Thanks, this definitely gets the thread ID for the current thread.

Comment: FWIW android.os.Process.getThreadPriority(android.os.Process.myTid());

Comment: Note that this returns the thread's priority, to answer the OPs question more directly:  call `android.os.Process.myTID()` to fetch the ID of the given thread as a string.

Answer (score 14):

While we are working with threads. We also want to log thread details to solve thread related problem. Create one Utils class as below and use it to log thread signature.

```
public class Utils 
{
   public static long getThreadId()
   {
      Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
      return t.getId();
   }

   public static String getThreadSignature()
   {
      Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
      long l = t.getId();
      String name = t.getName();
      long p = t.getPriority();
      String gname = t.getThreadGroup().getName();
      return (name 
            + ":(id)" + l 
            + ":(priority)" + p
            + ":(group)" + gname);
   }

   public static void logThreadSignature()
   {
      Log.d("ThreadUtils", getThreadSignature());
   }

   public static void sleepForInSecs(int secs)
   {
      try
      {
         Thread.sleep(secs * 1000);
      }
      catch(InterruptedException x)
      {
         throw new RuntimeException("interrupted",x);
      }
   }
```

Reference : [www.androidbook.com](http://www.androidbook.com/akc/display?url=displaynoteimpurl&ownerUserId=android&reportId=3504)