# Android - Get thread id - returns always 0 with this SO-approach

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am trying to get a threads id.
I use this approach :

[How to get Android Thread ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8332475/how-to-get-android-thread-id)

But the recommended way always returns 0.

This line does,what it should

Thread.currentThread.getID().

Which is the right one ?

Comment: What are you going to *do* with the thread ID once you have it?  There are multiple thread IDs (the system TID, the Dalvik TID, the java.lang.Thread ID).

Answer (score 6):

`Thread.currentThread().getId();`
According to [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#getId%28%29)

> Returns the thread's identifier. The ID is a positive long generated on thread creation, is unique to the thread, and doesn't change during the lifetime of the thread; the ID may be reused after the thread has been terminated.

`android.os.Process.myTid();`
According to [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process.html#myTid%28%29)

> Returns the identifier of the calling thread, which be used with setThreadPriority(int, int).

According to my understanding, `Thread.currentThread().getId();` will return the Thread Id by which a user or running program can identify a thread while on the other hand `android.os.Process.myTid();` will provide the id by which the processor or running machine identifies a thread and this will be unique and I do not think the same id by this can be assigned to any other thread once it is dead.

Comment: So, in order to use THE RIGHT ONE and distinguish between android-java-runtime-threads this is the proper way ?

Thread.currentThread().getId().  Right ?

Comment: yes, I also think  `Thread.currentThread().getId(`) will provide you the distinguish ID but it can not be used with `android.os.Process` class method and are you getting the thread id or using the function `android.os.Process.getThreadPriority`

Answer (score 0):

These are 2 different things.

```
Thread.currentThread().getID();
```

returns the thread ID of the `Thread` within the Virtual machine as `long`.

```
android.os.Process.myTid();
```

returns the "Thread identifier" as an `int`. "Thread identifier" is a value that can be used to control processes at the Linux level and has nothing to do with the Virtual machine. This value is used in calls to `android.os.Process.setThreadPriority()` and `android.os.Process.getThreadPriority()`.