# How to get thread ID in Android

Tags: android, multithreading

Suppose in the following example, I use `Thread.currentThread().getId()` at lines `a` and `b` to output the thread IDs as suggested by many answers.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId()); // line a
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId()); // line b
        }
    }).run();
}
```

Since line `a` is executed in the UI thread and line `b` is executed in another thread, I assume the output thread IDs should be different. However, both of line `a` and line `b` output 1.

Is my understanding on `Thread.currentThread().getId()` correct or I miss use the API?

Comment: This may help you: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25730340/why-does-one-background-thread-have-the-same-thread-id-as-the-main-service-threa

Comment: You can also take a look at [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8333167/12103664).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the reason. It is because I should call the `start` method of the `Thread` rather than the `run` method. It should be `new Thread(...).start();`